# How to calculate approximate age based on birth year?

Tags: sql, sqlite, date

There are several questions on SO about calculating age based on DOB. However, I have several tables where only `BirthYear` is provided. There is no month or day. I would like to simply take the current year and subtract the value in `BirthYear` from that to calculate an approximate age. As long as it is within a year or so, the accuracy doesn't matter to me as much.

I don't want to modify the table in any way. I just wanted an additional column with calculated age showing when I run the query. I keep seeing answers with `ALTER TABLE` or `UPDATE` statements but I don't think that would be the way to go here...

Currently I have a statement to order by birth year as well:

```
ORDER BY CAST(replace(replace(BirthYear,',',''),'$','') AS REAL) ASC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQLite, you can get the current year as:

```
select strftime('%Y', date('now'))
```

I don't know what `BirthYear` looks like, but you can do:

```
select (strftime('%Y', date('now')) - BirthYear) as age
```

Or whatever expression gets the birth year.

Comment: Wow, this works perfectly! Is there anyway I can name the column something like "Age" so the column name doesn't take up half the window?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DATEDIFF` function to achieve this result; instead of `ALTER`ing the existing table, a `VIEW` can be created that includes a calculated `ApproximateAge`column:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_MyTableWithAge
AS

SELECT  *
,       DATEDIFF(year, DOB, GETDATE()) AS ApproximateAge
FROM    MyTable
```

*year* is an input to the function, literally (no quotes). *DOB* is the column name in your table that stores the date of birth.

More info on DATEDIFF: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datediff.asp

***EDIT:*** I just saw this is SQLite, note MSSQL; here's the equivalent SQLite code:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_MyTableWithAge
AS

SELECT  *
,       strftime('%Y', date('now')) - DOB AS ApproximateAge
FROM    MyTable
```

`strftime` syntax borrowed from @Gordon Linoff's answer. More info on this function: https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/functions/strftime.php

Once the view is created, you can use it in place of your table. You can still order by the calculated age; the column is now treated as any other column would be in a table, but the original table is not modified in any way:

```
SELECT *
FROM   vw_MyTableWithAge
ORDER BY ApproximateAge ASC
```